# Tuple to Tuple conversion

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any easy way to convert `Tuple<int, string, Guid>` to `Tuple<int, string>`?

**UPDATE**:
... to convert `List<Tuple<int, string, Guid>>` to `List<Tuple<int, string>>` ?

Comment: Huh? You are looking to convert the same string value to itself? Please explain what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Aaah, that is a little clearer.

Comment: See update to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sure:

```
Tuple<int, string, Guid> t1 = ...;
Tuple<int, string> t2 = new Tuple<int, string>(t1.Item1, t1.Item2);
```

**Update:**
With the list:

```
List<Tuple<int, string, Guid>> t1s = ...;
List<Tuple<int, string>> t2s = t1s.Select(t1 => new Tuple<int, string>(t1.Item1, t1.Item2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

For the updated question...

```
var result = tuples.Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item1, t.Item2)).ToList();
```

...should do the trick.

This takes the original list `tuples` and projects each 3-tuple `t` into the desired 2-tuple; the result of this is an `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>>` which may be sufficient if you can work with a lazy sequence, but as you've indicated you want a list then this is possible by appending a `.ToList()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNewList = myList.Select(t => new Tuple<int, string>(t.Item1, t.Item2)).ToList();
```